# Is there any modern Active Directory management programs for Linux

Tags: active-directory

My boss has told me that I would be allowed to run Linux (instead of Windows7) on my work PC if I can still manage MS Active Directory within it - not using an RDP.  I searched and see suggestions that were made for WinServer 2003 and older.  Are there any tools that work for managing AD that is running on WinServer 2008 and 2012?

Comment: Is a local Windows VM on your machine an option, bridged to the LAN, for Windows-specific management tools?

Comment: I think he wants to challenge my request, by demanding that it be directly in the OS - I know the Desktop Engineers do not allow VMs of Windows running within the LAN.

Answer (score 0):

There is Adaxes that allows you to do pretty much all AD-related tasks from a [web interface](http://www.adaxes.com/active-directory_web-interface.htm).

It's a third party tool that is probably more useful for automation, but it can do the trick. Maybe there's something similar out there with the same approach.

Comment: Not free, and pricing is expensive and done based on # of users.